# Hikari-- Connection is not available

Tags: hikaricp

HikariCP query error：
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: hikari-pool - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30001ms. Any clue would be helpful!

```
Hikari：3.2.0
Springboot：2.1.16.RELEASE
```

Hikari Pool multipully executes shuntdown and start as follow, and sometime the pool size seems more than `maximum-pool-size`, any idea?

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource|hikari-pool - Start completed.
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource|hikari-pool - Starting...

com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource|hikari-pool - Shutdown completed.
com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource|hikari-pool - Shutdown initiated...
```

hikaricp settings:

```
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=10
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=20
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=600000
spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1800000
spring.datasource.hikari.validation-timeout=300000
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name= hikari-pool
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1
```

error log:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: hikari-pool - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30001ms.
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:676)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:190)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:155)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:88)
at com.xxxx.xxxxxx.monitor.spring.cloud.starter.jdbc.JdbcAspect.getConnection(JdbcAspect.java:59)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor257.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:644)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:633)
at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f804f71c.getConnection(<generated>)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$eeb1ae86.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:750)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:689)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1fcd50ca.getConnection(<generated>)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)
... 67 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1187)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1182)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setNetworkTimeout(ConnectionImpl.java:5506)
at io.opentelemetry.javaagent.shaded.instrumentation.jdbc.internal.OpenTelemetryConnection.setNetworkTimeout(OpenTelemetryConnection.java:337)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.setNetworkTimeout(PoolBase.java:550)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.isConnectionAlive(PoolBase.java:165)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:179)
```

Comment: Start with the basics: try using a primitive tool such as telnet to test the host/port for the MySQL server is reachable from the machine you are running this code on.  e.g. `telnet 127.0.0.1 3306`.  If you can reach the port you will see a version number  and the connection will likely abruptly close.

Comment: @AndrewL Well, mysql is the common service of our production enviroment, I think the network is ok.